# How to copy all website with selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I used webdriver, because I need to make to copy the site after authentication.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import myconnutils
import re
from time import sleep

connection = myconnutils.getConnection()

#use Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/User/Documents/sender/chromedriver")

#enter to site
driver.get("https://example.com/en/account")
driver.find_element_by_id("user").send_keys("userlogin")
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("passwordinput")
driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
```

What is next? How to copy all page with css, js, images?

Comment: do you want to copy the whole html? , selenium doesn't work that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually try using Selenium with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). You should be able to get the source code like this:

```
example_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

Eventually [this blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-using-selenium-and-beautifulsoup-99195cd70a58) also helps.